# Show that standard Brownian motion has Feller property.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider the standard brownian motion $(W_{t})$, it is known that $W$ is a homogenous Markov process and thus it makes sense to consider if $W$ has Feller property.

Let $f$ be a bounded continuous function, to show $W$ is Feller, we need to show the semi-groups $$p^{t}f(x_{1})-p^{t}f(x_{2})\longrightarrow 0\ \ \text{as}\ \ x_{1}\longrightarrow x_{2}.$$

By definition we have 
\begin{align*}
p^{t}f(x_{1})-p^{t}f(x_{2})&=\mathbb{E}[f(W_{t})|W_{0}=x_{1}]-\mathbb{E}[f(W_{t})|W_{0}=x_{2}]\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(t, x_{1}, dy)f(y)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(t, x_{2}, dy)f(y).
\end{align*}
But we know the formula of transition probability of Wiener process: $$\mathbb{P}(t, x, \Gamma)=\int_{\Gamma}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{-(y-x)^{2}}{2t}}dy,$$ hence the density must be $$\mathbb{P}(t, x, dy)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{-(y-x)^{2}}{2t}}dy.$$

This implies that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(t, x, dy)f(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{-(y-x)^{2}}{2t}}f(y)dy,$$ and a change of variable $\tilde{y}+x:=y$ gives us $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{-(y-x)^{2}}{2t}}f(y)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{-\tilde{y}^{2}}{2t}}f(\tilde{y}+x)=\mathbb{E}(f(W_{t}+x)).$$

Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
p^{t}f(x_{1})-p^{t}f(x_{2})&=\mathbb{E}(f(W_{t}+x_{1}))-\mathbb{E}(f(W_{t}+x_{2}))\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big(f(W_{t}+x_{1})-f(W_{t}+x_{2})\Big).
\end{align*}

What should I do next? Can I directly conclude as $x_{1}\rightarrow x_{2}$, $$\mathbb{E}\Big(f(W_{t}+x_{1})-f(W_{t}+x_{2})\Big)\longrightarrow 0?$$

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: apply the dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @Michh so since $f$ is bounded, $f(W_{t}+x_{1})-f(W_{t}+x_{2})$ is bounded. And since $f$ is continuous, as $x_{1}\rightarrow x_{2}$, we must have $f(W_{t}+x_{1})-f(W_{t}+x_{2})\rightarrow 0$. Hence the dominated convergence theorem gives me the desired result?

Comment: @Michh do I need to separate it into $\mathbb{1}_{\{|W_{t}|\leq R\}}$ and  $\mathbb{1}_{\{|W_{t}|> R\}}$?

Comment: Your first argument is correct and sufficient! Also you can apply DCT directly to show that $x \mapsto \mathbb{E}(f(W_t+x))$ is continuous (without needing $x_1$ and $x_2$, but that's just a question of taste I suppose).

Comment: @Michh okay. thank you so much! This is actually a theorem in my course note but roughly proved. I managed to fill several gaps, but cannot understand why it separates into $\mathbb{1}_{\{|W_{t}|\leq R\}}$ and  $\mathbb{1}_{\{|W_{t}|> R\}}$ and the note also argues that the first one is small due to the uniform continuity of $f$ on bounded intervals the second is small if $R$ large.....

Comment: @Michh But you have confirmed that we don't need to separate. So problem solved! Thank you!!

Comment: Note however that this doesn't prove that it's a [Feller process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller_process).

Comment: @Michh Ah! Sorry, I mean to prove that it has Feller property. Let me edit my post.

Comment: @Michh Thanks for noticing this!

Comment: @Michh oh by the way do you want to post a short answer so that I can give you upvote and accept? I will answer my own post instead if you don't want to do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded, we know that $f(W_{t}+x_{1})-f(W_{t}+x_{2})$ is also bounded. And since $f$ is continuous, as $x_{1}\rightarrow x_{2}$, we must have $f(W_{t}+x_{1})-f(W_{t}+x_{2})\rightarrow 0$.

It then follows from bounded convergence theorem that $$p^{t}f(x_{1})-p^{t}f(x_{2})\longrightarrow 0\ \text{as}\ x_{1}\rightarrow x_{2}.$$